# Should we create a script to run "clean-up" tasks, or should we do it in program directly?

Tags: c#, powershell

I'm always discussing the following topic with a co-worker:

Example:

We have written a C# program that sends our order confirmations and offers to our customers. it reads data directly from our ERP, creates a PDF out of the data, then sends it to the correct customer. Of course there is a bit more to it in detail, but that's basically it.

Now, all the PDF that got successfully sent to the customer, will be moved to an archive directory by the program.

The task is now to delete each 10th of the month (April 10th, Mai 10th etc.) all archive PDF that are older than 3 months.

I created a working PowerShell solution that is started via scheduled task and does this deleting. But my co-worker now wants our programmer to add this functionality to the program itself, so that the program does this once a month.

What would be the best practise / when should we use a script and when should we implement something in the program itself? Can you point me into the right direction?

In my opinion, periodical clean-up tasks should be done via script, but how can I argue this to my co-worker?

if this is off-topic here, please point me to where I can ask this.

Comment: I prefer to do everything in Code. but i think it is more of a opinion thing. Code/Script it both works.

Comment: If you seperate functionality into discrete items, you can for example, upgrade / enhance your seperate 'archiver' module without affecting your PDF generator. They seem like two different functions and a logical point of seperation.

Answer (score 0):

That is really a judgement call from you.

Having multiple mini scripts though can be very annoying for managing code, keeping everything in one place where possible keeps stuff simplified.

Personal advice is to have one cron managing program on a system that contains any small code snippets like this that you call from command line arguments.

As far as I can tell both of these tasks are cron based just one cron is shorter that the other?

My only advice really is avoid ending up with hundreds of mini programs/scripts, especially if they have any shared functionality.